# Enable Emmet inside Sass Map for PhpStorm 10

Tags: sass, phpstorm, emmet

Sublime doesn't have any problem with this, but PhpStorm seems very picky about where it expands Emmet abbreviations. For instance, if I try to write an Emmet abbreviation inside of a Sass map, it won't expand:

```
$sass-map: (
    w100p
)
```

Anybody know how to enable Emmet for all contexts in a PhpStorm Sass file?

Comment: You may try "Emmet Everywhere" plugin -- maybe it will do any better than what IDE offers by default;

Comment: I tried that plugin, but it only works for HTML templates, not CSS, unfortunately.

Comment: Well ... that `w100p` abbreviation works in `.less`/`.scss` files for sure -- just inside ordinary classes/ids (e.g. `.myItem { w100p[TAB] }`). But it does not work inside constructions like you have: `$sass-map: ( HERE )`. I've just re-checked this in PhpStorm v10.0.3 (same as WebStorm v11).  Based on the above I may only suggest to file a ticket to the Issue Tracker at https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/WEB (or at least check for possible existing tickets)